# PHP variable scope in a static method

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I'm having trouble getting access to a variable that is available outside of my method call.  (Using Laravel)  An example:

```
    print "Here is my name: $name\n";

    return Foo::find(1)->whereHas('bar', function($q) {
        global $name;
        print "Unfortunately this name is blank: " . $name;
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
    })->first();
```

$name inside the whereHas function is always blank.  If I don't declare it as $global, then I get a warning that $name doesn't exist at all.  How do I get access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send references to anonymous functions (i.e., Closures) with the `use` keyword:

```
$name = 'foo';
return Foo::find(1)->whereHas('bar', function($q) use ($name) {
    print "Here name should be : " . $name; // foo
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
})->first();
```

btw i have not tested this, but its supposed to work

Comment: Nice shot sir!  I had no idea about the use() keyword.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks!